# Generating DocuSign Recipient View by using template recipient role name?

Tags: docusignapi

Here is what I am trying to do.

1. I create a docusign template by calling their rest api. In that call I specify 2 signers with

   ```
       "signers": [
       { "RecipientId": 1, "RoleName": "role1", "routingOrder": 1 },
       { "RecipientId": 2, "RoleName": "role2", "routingOrder": 2 }
   ]
   ```
2. Then I generate sender view url and redirect to that url. In docusign, i see recipients being populated correctly.
3. I add 2 sign here tabs.
4. I assign one signhere to role1, and the other to role2.
5. Then I make call for generating recipient url, but just can't get it right.

How can I get recipient view url by providing recipient id or role?

I keep getting the following response.

```
{
"errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
"message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the 
specified envelope."
}
```

Here is my request body

```
{
"returnUrl": "hidden",
"clientUserId": 1,
"recipientId": 1,
"UserName": "role1",
"Email": "fake@test.com",
"AuthenticationMethod": "Email"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't support changing the routing order when populating the `role` attributes. Instead you need to change the recipients explicitly.

Comment: I don't want to change routing order. It is already defined in template creation. I just want to get recipient into the recipient view with a certain role so that he can only sign the signhere tab that his role got assigned to.